# Can a git Server-Side Hook detect when a conflict is being resolved?

Tags: git

I'd like to take action server-side when any merge commit that resolves a conflict is pushed to the server. Specifically I'd like to notify other authors to review the merge to make sure their work is unaffected, so I am wondering if there's a way that a git server-side (pre-receive or post-receive) can *both* detect that the commit is a merge *and* know which line(s) contained resolved conflicts? (that way it could `git blame` an earlier rev and find authors to notify)

Comment: Rerun incoming merges on the server and see whether they produce the same results as the results being pushed.  Any differences are conflict resolutions or other interesting hand-crafted changes to the automerge results.

Answer (score 4):

Detecting that a commit is a merge commit is easy: it has more than one parent.

Detecting that a commit is the result of the merge *code* is impossible in general, as such commits are not marked in any way.  Cherry-picked and reverted commits are outputs of the merge code, and they are sometimes marked as such in their commit messages; but these are just special cases.  Using `git merge --squash`, anyone can invoke the merge-as-a-verb process, but make an ordinary, non-merge commit.  One can make a policy rule that committers must mark their conflicts, but it's not easy to enforce.  Git used to write these out as part of its default commit message for later, and still does to some extent, but they are normally commented-out.

In any case, assuming you're satisfied with detecting merge commits via the "more than one parent" method (i.e., ignoring squash-merge and other special cases), it's still tricky to go from "this is  a merge" to "this is a merge that had some conflicts".  It *is* possible to find out mechanically that there were conflicts: just re-perform the merge, using a detached HEAD, for each commit that was a merge commit.  It's also possible at that point to compare the merge result, if Git is able to merge it on its own, to the committed merge result: just use `git diff-tree` to compare the two commits' trees.  Hence:

```
if (commit $H is a merge):
    get list of all of $H parents
    git checkout $list[0]  # assuming a zero subscript means first
    git merge --quiet $list[1:N-1]
    if (last command succeeded):
        difference=$(git diff-tree -r HEAD $H)
        if (no difference):
            commit was entirely mechanical
        else:
            commit is suspicious
    else:
        commit has conflicts
        git reset --hard HEAD # discard work-tree
```

(This process must be run in a repository that has a work-tree, or using a temporary work-tree via `git --work-tree=<path>`.)

If the merge has conflicts, finding the conflicted lines, and detecting the author, will be tricky.

Comment: Thanks! This is nowhere near as simple as I was hoping for _but_ your answer gives me all the parts necessary should I want to automate this. (I'm not sure it's worth the value, a simple "team: here's the new policy" may do in this case)